# Can I use two sets of I/O devices for two user sessions on one computer?

Tags: linux, xorg, console, multiseat

I want to connect a second monitor, keyboard and mouse to my PC (running Ubuntu) and let somebody else (e.g. my son) use the a different TTY while I am working.

I know I can switch between TTYs using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd>, and that I could potentially start several X sessions (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[7-12]</kbd>), but is it possible to use them at the same time with different I/O devices?

In a way I'd like to emulate the way computers used to work in the old days, when you'd have a central machine with several "terminals" attached. Linux (and Unix style OSs) are generally designed for that, so it should be possible, right?

Comment: @Anko, thanks for your editing...made the problem much clearer!

Comment: No problem; happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a guide](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html) on Linux Gazette for a six-headed X11 system.

It works by giving a different `ServerLayout` in the `xorg.conf`, grouping the different screen, mouse, keyboard. Each screen has its own GDM instance/session.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question beyond that it's possible. What are you not allowed to link to?

Comment: @anko It tells "links to linux gazette are not allowed"

Comment: That seems odd. I just edited with a link [here](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html) and got no such message. (My edit in the review queue now.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!